# NSXMLParser in swift

Tags: swift, nsxmlparser

Explain me how to?
I need to parse some xml

I have code

```
import UIKit    

class Parse: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate{
var test = ""
var test1 = ""
func beginparse() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/qwe.xml")
    let xml = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url!)
    xml?.delegate = self
    xml?.parse()
}
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]){
    test += elementName
    print("Element`s name is \(test)")
    print("Element`s attributes are\(attributeDict)")
}
}
var ins = Parse()
ins.beginparse()
```

When i change url to

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/smth/smth.cgi?get=0-200")
```

its stop working
what i need to change.

Maybe i need to use other function to parse http response?
Thanks you.

P.S. I'm new in swift :)

Comment: what does http://example.com/smth/smth.cgi?get=0-200 send back to the client?

Comment: @luk2302 Its send back xml. at "http://example.com/qwe.xml" I Copied answer from " example.com/smth/smth.cgi?get=0-200" and its works, but if i try to use it direct its didn't work

Comment: If it works for first URL, but doesn't for for another, make sure you have valid XML in second URL. Also I would like to recommend make your `xml` property, not a local variable.

Comment: @AlexanderDoloz i have idea that its doesn't work for second url, because its 'Response' for 'HTTPMethod=Get', but i need help to verify it, i don't know how to parse http response :(